# Surface oxidation rates in CO2 vs Nitrogen vs Air?

Tags: arc, gas

Is there a difference in surface oxidation and formation of electrical arcs on electrical contacts in ambient CO2 and N2 and Air? Can the surface oxidation difference be quantified?

Comment: Are you talking about oxidation, the chemical reaction involving oxygen, which therefore cant happen without oxygen, or oxidation as the more general chemistry definition?

Comment: Yes, good point, it's because I wrote the question with only CO2, and added Nitrogen as an afterthought. I mean surface degradation from plasma equivalent to oxidation. i.e. do electrical arcs turn some of the CO2 to oxygen and carbon? what about the N2? what happens?

Comment: If they decompose the CO2 it just recombines. CO2 is low energy. I imagine same thing happens with N2 for the same reason.